# Countdown to ON timer switch for appliances?

Tags: switches

I have an unusual application for a countdown timer switch.

I need to turn OFF a refrigerator for a  limited amount of time and have it automatically turn back ON after the timer expires.

The purpose of this is to ensure there is not an annoying hum from the compressor while watching TV near a wine refrigerator.

The wine is going to be just fine with the compressor disabled for a couple of hours but I don't want to ever forget to turn it back on after I'm done watching my movie or whatever.

I've been searching for a countdown timer switch that can do this but so far have only found switches that will turn the power ON temporarily and then turn it back OFF after a specified amount of time.  I need the opposite.

Is there such as thing as a countdown timer switch that counts down and switches ON rather than OFF after the timer expires?

If not, is there anything analogous to a NOT gate for appliance-level AC power which when powered switches another circuit OFF and when unpowered, switches another circuit ON?

Answer (score 1):

Use an 'on delay' timer, just turn it off and then straight back on again whenever you want the fridge off for a period. The fridge will turn off and then back on after the preset (adjustable) interval has elapsed.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a regular count down timer switch a relay with a break contact